# Getting rid of the apostrophe in subprocess.Popen to move files

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen, mv

My script generates multiple files that contain random names based on the info it extracts. I created this test to try and move all new files created while running into a new directory named after the file being ran.

When I use `os.popen("mv " + moveFiles +' ' + filename + "_dir")` it works just fine, but os.popen is considered insecure due to shellshock

When switching to `cmd = Popen(["mv", str(moveFiles), filename + "_dir"])`, I get the following error

> mv: cannot stat '/home/test/testing/TestFile1.txt
> /home/test/testing/TestFile2.txt': No such file or directory

I believe this is due to it adding the apostrophe at the beginning and end of the moveFiles variable which tries to move it as 1 file rather than 2. So it works when a single file is created, but anymore results in the error. Is there a way to remove this?

```
'/home/test/testing/TestFile1.txt /home/test/testing/TestFile2.txt'
```

```
def createDir(filename):
    """
    createDir creates the folder of the file/argument given (Example.txt_dir)
    """
    Dir = str(filename) + "_dir"
    cmd = Popen(["mkdir", Dir], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) 

def createFiles(filename):
    """
    createFiles creates test files to move into Example.txt_dir
    """
    with open('TestFile1.txt', 'w') as m:
        cmd = Popen(["file", filename], stdout=m, stderr=PIPE)
    print('Saved as TestFile1.txt')

    with open('TestFile2.txt', 'w') as m:
        cmd = Popen(["file", filename], stdout=m, stderr=PIPE)
    print('Saved as TestFile2.txt')

def dirDifference(dir1, dir2):
    """
    dirDifference compares 2 paths, 1 before being ran and 1 after to get a list of all new files to be moved
    """
    #Compares Directory before and after running
    dif = [i for i in dir1 + dir2 if i not in dir1 or i not in dir2]
    separator =  ' '
    x = separator.join(map(str, dif)) 
    return x

def moveDir(filename, moveFiles):
    """
    moveDir: Moves the new files to the directory.
    """
    Dir = str(filename) + "_dir"
    cmd = Popen(["mv", moveFiles, filename + "_dir"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct: the problem is that you have two filenames joined together with a space. Since you're using `Popen()` and not `os.popen()` you're bypassing shell interpretation of the arguments, which means that individual filenames aren't getting separated. This is the same as if you had used quotes on the command line:

```
mv 'file1 file2' destination
mv: cannot stat 'file1 file2': No such file or directory
```

You've asked it to move a single file whose name has a space in the middle. What you need to do is make each filename a separate element in the list in `Popen()`:

```
cmd = Popen(["mv", file1, file2, destination])
```

In the case of your code above, instead of `dirDifference()` returning filenames joined together with spaces, it could simply return a list, which you could use with `Popen()`:

```
cmd = Popen(["mv"] + moveFiles + [filename + "_dir"])
```

(making sure that `moveFiles` is a non-empty list of course)

Comment: haha! It worked, just had to remove the last 3 lines of dirDifference and use your bottom response. Thanks alot!